# Importing Url's of sheets shared with me into google sheets automatically whenever one is shared

Tags: google-sheets, scripting, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-apps-script-editor

I'm pretty new to excel or google sheets. The work place, that I work at does not have anything stream lined.

I'm trying to create my own work book that I can refresh everyday I log in so that I can have a list of things that I need to work on for that day.

One of the functions that I would like to have is, whenever a new sheet is shared with me on Google Sheets, I want the URL for that sheet to populate in one of the cells in my workbook automatically and arranged based on timestamp.

I was trying to search for this on Google, but I read that: shared with me docs are not stored anywhere specifically.

Any help or pointing me in the right direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: most likely not possible if no one answers it

Comment: Hey @Santosh, was the answer I published useful to you? I'd love to know how you moved on with the issue you originally presented. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to fetch the files that have been shared with you. For that, you can simply call the Drive API's [`Files: list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) method specifying in the `q` parameter the `sharedWithMe` attribute.

Afterwards, you can use the [`SpreadsheetApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) class to gather a spreadsheet and insert data into it. In this case, you can simply make several calls of [`apendRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents) to insert the results.

Finally, [properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties) can be used to store the status of the script (last date checked), so that it can know where to resume from. In this case below, we'll be saving the date in the `LAST_DATE` property.

*Code.gs*

```js
var SPREADSHEET_ID = 'YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID';
var SHEET_NAME = 'YOUR_SHEET_NAME';

function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var lastDate = new Date(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('LAST_DATE'));
  var currentDate = new Date();

  var files = getFiles(lastDate);

  for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    var row = [
      new Date(files[i].sharedWithMeDate),
      files[i].title,
      files[i].alternateLink,
      files[i].sharingUser.emailAddress,
      files[i].owners.map(getEmail).join(', ')];
    sheet.appendRow(row);
  }

  console.log('lastDate: %s, currentDate: %s, events added: %d', lastDate, currentDate, files.length);

  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('LAST_DATE', currentDate.toISOString());
}

function getEmail(user) {
  return user.emailAddress;
}

function getFiles(lastSharedDate) {
  var query = "sharedWithMe and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'";

  var res = Drive.Files.list({
    q: query,
    orderBy: "sharedWithMeDate desc",
    fields: "*",
    pageSize: 1000
  });

  // `query` parameter cannot compare sharedWithMeDate, so we do it afterwards
  return res.items.filter(function (i) {
    return (new Date(i.sharedWithMeDate) > lastSharedDate);
  }).reverse();
}
```

You can set up the script to be ran periodically (i.e once a day, or more in case you'd need it) using [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).